# Enable charging while in MTP mode on Android

Tags: usb, charging, mtp

When I connect my Android device (a Samsung Galaxy Tab E with Android 4.4.4) to a PC in MTP mode, the tablet always shows the USB charging being disabled, which makes sense because the USB port of a PC might not be designed to drive a high current.

Now I have a Y USB cable that allows two inputs (one for power connecting wires GND and VCC and one for data connecting wires D+ and D-) to connect to a single output that is my Android device.

I want to force my Android device to both communicate in MTP mode with the PC **and** charge its battery through the same cable. How can I do that?

FYI I am perfectly OK with the idea of flashing a custom Android image to my device.

Comment: I was under the impression that all Android devices charged battery when connected to USB, regardless of mode

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to be the case with SM-T560 and Kitkat